# How do I code a filthy rich gradient-painted border using Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, awt, border, gradient

Revised: The problem is to paint a four sided border where each side starts with a solid base color and fades to white inward over the span of the border. The challenge was to make the intersection of the borders look seamless. To accomplish this, one may draw the borders, then use triangles to 'blend' the corners. Two triangles may be used per corner if there is no overlap in the rectangles drawing the broder, or one triangle per corner is sufficient (as shown below) if two parallel border sides extend the full length of the border (ie the rectangles overlap).

```
    private static final int GRADIENT_LENGTH = 29;
    private static final int BAR_LENGTH = 25;
    public static void paintGradientBorder(Graphics g, Color borderColor) {
```

```
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();

    GradientPaint gradientColorWest = new GradientPaint(0, 0, borderColor,
            GRADIENT_LENGTH, 0, Color.WHITE);
    GradientPaint gradientColorEast = new GradientPaint(WINDOW_WIDTH - GRADIENT_LENGTH,
            0, Color.WHITE, WINDOW_WIDTH, 0, borderColor);
    GradientPaint gradientColorNorth= new GradientPaint(0, 0, borderColor, 0,
            GRADIENT_LENGTH, Color.WHITE);
    GradientPaint gradientColorSouth = new GradientPaint(0, WINDOW_HEIGHT - GRADIENT_LENGTH,
            Color.WHITE,0, WINDOW_HEIGHT, borderColor);

    //south bar
    g2.setPaint(gradientColorSouth);
    g2.fillRect(0, WINDOW_HEIGHT - BAR_LENGTH, WINDOW_WIDTH, BAR_LENGTH);
    //north bar
    g2.setPaint(gradientColorNorth);
    g2.fillRect(0, 0, WINDOW_WIDTH, BAR_LENGTH);
    //west bar
    g2.setPaint(gradientColorWest);
    g2.fillRect(0, BAR_LENGTH, BAR_LENGTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT - BAR_LENGTH * 2);
    //east bar
    g2.setPaint(gradientColorEast);
    g2.fillRect(WINDOW_WIDTH - BAR_LENGTH, BAR_LENGTH, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT - BAR_LENGTH * 2);

    //NORTH WEST CORNER
    //left triangle
    Polygon p = new Polygon();        
    p.addPoint(0, 0);
    p.addPoint(BAR_LENGTH, BAR_LENGTH);
    p.addPoint(0, BAR_LENGTH);
    g2.setPaint(gradientColorWest);
    g2.fillPolygon(p);        
    //NORTH EAST CORNER
    //right triangle
    p.reset();
    p.addPoint(WINDOW_WIDTH, 0);
    p.addPoint(WINDOW_WIDTH - BAR_LENGTH, BAR_LENGTH);
    p.addPoint(WINDOW_WIDTH, BAR_LENGTH);
    g2.setPaint(gradientColorEast);
    g2.fillPolygon(p);
    //SOUTH WEST CORNER
    //left triangle
    p.reset();
    p.addPoint(0, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
    p.addPoint(0,WINDOW_HEIGHT - BAR_LENGTH);
    p.addPoint(BAR_LENGTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT - BAR_LENGTH);
    g2.setPaint(gradientColorWest);
    g2.fillPolygon(p);
    //SOUTH EAST CORNER
    //right triangle
    p.reset();
    p.addPoint(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
    p.addPoint(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT - BAR_LENGTH);
    p.addPoint(WINDOW_WIDTH - BAR_LENGTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT - BAR_LENGTH);
    g2.setPaint(gradientColorEast);
    g2.fillPolygon(p);

    g2.dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What if you don't intersect the rectangles but instead use a polygon (GeneralPath)?

```
GeneralPath topBox = new GeneralPath();
topBox.moveTo(0, 0);
// upper right
topBox.lineTo(width, 0);
// lower right; move diagonally down and to the left as in a picture frame
topBox.lineTo(width - (insetX / 2), 0 + (insetY / 2));
// lower left
topBox.lineTo((insetX / 2), 0 + (insetY / 2));
topBox.closePath();
g2.fill(topBox);
```

[image]

That way the rectangles will not overlap, but instead you'll have nice crisp edges between the different segments.

Comment: Used two triangles per corner. Works perfect. Thanks dude. True Baller Status.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than creating and painting 4 rectangles, I would create a single `Shape` representing your border area by subtracting an inner rectangle from an outer one using `Area`:

```
Area area = new Area(new Rectangle2D.Double(...));
Area inner = new Area(new Rectangle2D.Double(...));
area.subtract(inner);

g2.setPaint(new GradientPaint(...));
g2.fill(area);
```

Comment: What type of gradient paint object would facilitate painting a solid color on all four sides, then fading toward the center?

Comment: @cs student: Well, this probably wouldn't be ideal for that. @I82Much's solution seems reasonable. You didn't specify in the question what kind of gradient you wanted to make and I didn't take the time to interpret all the code you posted to figure it out. You can make some pretty nice looking gradient borders that have one main gradient that applies to them like this though.